# Is shampoo or soap a better emulsifier?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

Made homemade shampoo using:

1. Sodium lauryl sulfate (SLS)
2. Glycerin
3. 95% ethanol
4. Sodium stearate

Made homemade soap using:

1. 20% sodium hydroxide
2. Vegetable oil
3. 95% ethanol
4. 20% sodium chloride

After doing an oil-in-water emulsion test, it showed that my shampoo was the better emulsifier, but I was expecting it to be the soap since a lot of resources have said it should be.  There's potential I could have mixed them up on accident, but I think it was okay... do my results make sense or do they seem incorrect?  Please explain.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to this.  Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid that that measuring emulsification is not that easy. The statement that soap or shampoo is a better emulsifier cannot be generalized. My suggestion is not to use homemade shampoos etc. The problem is that you do not know the purity of chemicals. Was ethanol pure? Did it contain harmful substances? You would never know.

Comment: Your raw materials are irrelevant, if all you care about is *which is the better emulsifier*. What counts is *how* you measured that: how much shampoo vs. how much soap (do you measure in moles, by volume, by weight?), what substance you're emulsifying (n-dodecane? peanut butter?), what procedure (shaken? stirred?)...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which proportion of these four components do you mix ?